# How to use GPT-J for paraphrasing

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Could anyone point me to direction how to use GPT-J model for text paraphrasing . As generating text is easy, but paraphrasing?
Do I need to fine tune on paraphrasing dataset? Or could I just use few shot training?

Comment: Please provide some additional context on what *specifically* you are looking for; it might be worth checking out [ask] and [mcve] to see how the question can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

GPT-J is very good at paraphrasing content. In order to achieve this, you have to do 2 things:

- Properly use few-shot learning (aka "prompting")
- Play with the top p and temperature parameters

Here is a few-shot example you could use:

```
[Original]: Algeria recalled its ambassador to Paris on Saturday and closed its airspace to French military planes a day later after the French president made comments about the northern Africa country. 
[Paraphrase]: Last Saturday, the Algerian government recalled its ambassador and stopped accepting French military airplanes in its airspace. It happened one day after the French president made comments about Algeria.
###
[Original]: President Macron was quoted as saying the former French colony was ruled by a "political-military system" with an official history that was based not on truth, but on hatred of France.
[Paraphrase]: Emmanuel Macron said that the former colony was lying and angry at France. He also said that the country was ruled by a "political-military system".
###
[Original]: The diplomatic spat came days after France cut the number of visas it issues for citizens of Algeria and other North African countries.
[Paraphrase]: Diplomatic issues started appearing when France decided to stop granting visas to Algerian people and other North African people.
###
[Original]: After a war lasting 20 years, following the decision taken first by President Trump and then by President Biden to withdraw American troops, Kabul, the capital of Afghanistan, fell within a few hours to the Taliban, without resistance.
[Paraphrase]:
```

Depending on whether you want GPT-J to stick to the original, or be more creative, you should respectively decrease or increase top p and temperature.

I actually wrote an article about few-shot learning with GPT-J that you might find useful: [effectively using GPT-J with few-shot learning](https://nlpcloud.io/effectively-using-gpt-j-gpt-neo-gpt-3-alternatives-few-shot-learning.html?utm_source=so&utm_campaign=ie5u8885-fd8e-21eb-ca80-5242ac13d5ja)

Answer (score 1):

GPT does only one thing: completing the input you provide it with. This means the main attribute you use to control GPT is the input.

A good way of approaching a certain use-case is to explicitly write out what the task of the model should be + inserting the needed variables + initializing the task.

In your use-case this would be something like this (actual demo using GPT-J):

Input:

```
Paraphrase the sentence.
Sentence: The dog was scared of the cat.
Paraphrase:
```

Output:

```
Paraphrase the sentence.
Sentence: The dog was scared of the cat.
Paraphrase: The cat scared the dog.
```